# What is the difference between a research statement and a research interest?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, research-topic

is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

This would depend on who is asking, of course. But I'd expect, generally, that a research statement would be more detailed with a plan for how you would go about things like obtaining funding and incorporating students, etc. A research interest might be as little as you area of special expertise, though it might be a mistake to make it *too* narrow. For example, in mathematics, Algebra might be a bit too wide, but not so narrow that only a few people in the world are interested.

But, it can vary. Ask the asker for guidance if you can.